# Unable to connect with Tomcat from Android Device

Tags: java, android, windows, networking

I'm trying to access my application running on my laptop from Android tablet device. Both my laptop and tablet are on same network. I've turned off firewall setting in my laptop. But when I'm trying to access tomcat then its not responding. I tried to open from browser to access `http://<hostname:8080>` but not able open tomcat home page. Getting error message connection timeout.

Answer (score 2):

instead of hostname use `10.0.2.2`

Edit: As per OP's comment below the actual issue was ip was not accessible from remove device due to antivirus restrictions

Comment: Actually I'm using ip address only. I mentioned hostname here.

Comment: yes then use this ip address, it maps to localhost in virtual network in emulator

Comment: I'm not running it on emulator. It works fine in emulator. Issue is coming when trying to access from device. Its an issue with network only. But do not know how to reslove it.

Comment: both device and server are in same network and can you access that tomcat page from other computer in network ?

Comment: No, not able to connect from another computer on same network. some setting needs to be enable. But do not know what is the setting except firewall on my machine which I've already done.

Comment: can you ping that machine from other machine in the same network ?

Comment: looks like you are not in network then or some proxy is misconfigured

Comment: My laptop is on network, I can access internet from my server machine. Do you know how to check weather proxy is misconfigured?

Comment: if you can connect to internet that doesn't mean you are in same network, if you are in same network you should be able to ping other machine

Comment: I solved this issue. There was with antivirus installed on my machine. I uninstalled it and after did ipconfig/release and ipconfig/renew and restart laptop. Problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

#### Some pointers

Are you sure your tomcat is running and listening on port 8080? That and [the tomcat server logging](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging) together with debugging the app is what you should do.

Can you access other content exposed on the server from the android device? That you could also check if something else is available to work with. Just to rule out the network configuration here.

#### clarification needed

What do you mean by `I tried to open from browser ...`? Did you use the browser on your device or a browser on your computer? I would also try with a browser on the same device as the tomcat server. Then you can even try with localhost just to confirm that instance is running fine.

#### Tomcat troubleshooting

You can also check [this tomcat troubleshooting wiki page](https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Troubleshooting+Tomcat) or [the official Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. There was with antivirus installed on my machine. I uninstalled it and after did ipconfig/release and ipconfig/renew and restart laptop. Problem resolved.